# Unable to create Priority queue for Spring cloud stream apps from application yml

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-config

I am creating a spring cloud stream app for use with SCDF streams. I am trying to set the max-priority property of the consumer binding from application properties. But the queue that gets created is not priority queue.
I am able to create priority queue if I pass maxPriority as deployer property while creating the stream.

The settings I used in my yaml are as follows:-

```
spring:
  cloud: 
    stream: 
      rabbit: 
        bindings: 
          input:
            consumer:
              maxPriority: 10
```

I am using spring cloud rabbit binder version 2.1.3.Release

Can this property not be set using application yml file? I have a lot of applications in the stream and passing this property via deployer properties is extremely cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your YAML and it works fine for me

[image]

```yaml
spring:
  cloud: 
    stream: 
      rabbit: 
        bindings: 
          input:
            consumer:
              maxPriority: 10
      bindings:
        input:
          group: foo
```

The fact that it works for you via the deployer is suspicious; the runtime code is oblivious to how the properties are actually set. So, your YAML is not being used for some reason.

**EDIT**

It works for me with a config server too.

http://localhost:8080/actuator/env

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

With an anonymous consumer:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you @GaryRussell. I was using config server (app-name.yml) to fetch these settings. Once I moved these properties to the application.yml under src/main/resources it seems to work. All other properties are getting pulled from config server without any issues. I am not sure what I am missing. It seems this particular property has to be within the application.yml file under resources?

Comment: I just tested it with config server and it still works fine for me.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, I have similar configuration, I have not specified consumer group as SCDF handles it automatically.  Not sure why it is not creating priority queue.

```
spring:
    profiles: region1 
    cloud: 
      stream:
        rabbit: 
          bindings: 
            input:
              consumer:
              max-priority: 10
```

Comment: The env endpoint correctly shows the property:

**"spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.max-priority":{"value":10,"origin":null}**

Comment: With no group; we get an anonymous auto-delete queue - but it is still a priority queue for me - see the second edit.